# ¿Por que mi sweet Alert 2 no se muestra correctamente? PHP - CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, alert

el sweet alert se me muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi controller es:

```
public function modificarPersona($id){
    $errores = array();
    $mensaje = null;
    $apellido = trim($this->input->post('apellido'));
    $nombre = trim($this->input->post('nombre'));
    $dni = trim($this->input->post('dni'));

    $verificarIdPersona = $this->M_personas->verificarIdPersona($id);

      $datos = array(
        'apellido' => $apellido,
        'nombre' => $nombre,
        'dni' => $dni,
      );

      $edicion = $this->M_personas->editarPersona($id, $datos);
      if (!$edicion) {
        $mensaje = array(
          'success' => false,
          'message' => 'No se ha podido editar la persona, intente más tarde'
        );
      } else {
        $mensaje = array(
          'success' => true,
          'message' => 'Persona editada con éxito'
        );
      }
    if ($mensaje) {
      echo json_encode($mensaje);
    }
  }
```

y el js:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#formulario-edicion', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    var method = $(this).attr('method');
    var data = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: method,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#btn-edicion').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#btn-edicion').text('Editando...');
        },
        success: function(resp) {
            if (!resp.success) {
                swal.fire({
              title: 'Error!',
              text: resp.message,
              icon: 'error',
            })
              $('#btn-edicion').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#btn-edicion').text('Edicion persona');
            } else {
                swal.fire({
              title: 'Mensaje',
              text: resp.message,
                }).then(function() {
                    location.reload();
            });
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            swal.fire({
            title: 'Error',
            text: xhr.responseText,
            icon: 'error',
        })
            $('#btn-edicion').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#btn-edicion').text('Edicion persona');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: No se puede interpretar el JSON de la respuesta, porque hay un HTML que no debería estar ahí. Intenta agregar `exit;` después de esta línea: `echo json_encode($mensaje);`

Comment: Gracias @Triby
Cual seria el HTML que no deberia estar ????

Comment: En la imagen que pusiste hay un JSON, seguido de `<!DOCTYPE>...`, todo eso no debería estar ahí, porque impide que la petición AJAX interprete la respuesta.